# How to conditionally change setuptools compiler?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-cffi

I am building a C binding using the CFFI package. My project is being packaged for pypi so need to cover different operating systems. By default, setuptools uses the `MSVC` compiler for windows and the gnu gcc compiler for Linux.  I would like to conditionally change the compiler to `mingw32` if the operating system is windows. This is because parts of the C code base uses VLAs which MSVC does not support, and I would prefer to just change compiler instead of the whole codebase .

The only way I have been able to successfully change the compiler is with a `setup.cfg` file that looks like this:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler=mingw32
```

However I don't want to use setup.cfg because it is outdated, and I need to change the compiler option depending on the operating system which you can't do in a cfg file

Does anyone know how I can move this to `setup.py` so I can make it conditional?

Comment: If you're using CFFI, aren't you interfacing with pre-compiled C code? Can you give some more details on how your package is built now?

Comment: @AKX I have a C library that is being compiled into a C extension by CFFI + Setuptools (So called "API mode". There is no pre-compiled libraries). When I run `py -m build`, setuptools interacts with a python file that sets up compilation for my library with CFFI. You can see the project https://github.com/auto-optimization/eafpy

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `compiler` in the command-line using the option `--compiler` (i.e., `python setup.py build --compiler`).

To do this *conditionally*, you can override the `build` command class in the argument `cmdclass` of `setuptools.setup()` to set the `compiler` to use, like this:

```py
from setuptools.command.build import build as _build

class build(_build):
    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()

        if (...):
            self.compiler = "mingw32"
```

The `setup` would be:

```py
setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={"build": build},
    ...
)
```

You would do the same for `build_ext`.